Converting fn to method causes `type param not constrained` error
The generic function free_cmd works fine, but when I convert it to be a method of the Command, it causes unconstrained type errors.  How is it possible for the generic fn to be ok, but nearly-identical method variant not to be?
pub trait SliceWrapper<T> {
    fn slice(&self) -> &[T];
}

pub struct Command<SliceType: SliceWrapper<u8>> {
    data: SliceType,
}

pub trait AllocatedSlice<T>: SliceWrapper<T> + Default {}

pub trait Allocator<T> {
    type AllocatedMemory: AllocatedSlice<T>;
    fn free_cell(&mut self, data: Self::AllocatedMemory);
}

pub fn free_cmd<SliceTypeAllocator: Allocator<u8>>(
    xself: &mut Command<SliceTypeAllocator::AllocatedMemory>,
    alloc: &mut SliceTypeAllocator,
) {
    alloc.free_cell(core::mem::take(&mut xself.data));
}

My attempt:
impl<SliceTypeAllocator: Allocator<u8>> Command<SliceTypeAllocator::AllocatedMemory> {
    pub fn free_cmd(&mut self, alloc: &mut SliceTypeAllocator) {
        alloc.free_cell(core::mem::take(&mut self.data));
    }
}

error[E0207]: the type parameter `SliceTypeAllocator` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
|
| impl<SliceTypeAllocator: Allocator<u8>> Command<SliceTypeAllocator::AllocatedMemory> {
|      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unconstrained type parameter


With your current implementation, if multiple Allocator types have the same associated AllocatedMemory, this would yield conflicting impls for Command.
To work around this, you could add a generic trait that you can then implement for command:
pub trait FreeCmd<A: Allocator<u8>> {
    fn free_cmd(&mut self, alloc: &mut A);
}

impl<A: Allocator<u8>> FreeCmd<A> for Command<A::AllocatedMemory> 
{
    fn free_cmd(&mut self, alloc: &mut A) {
        alloc.free_cell(core::mem::take(&mut self.data));
    }
}


Thx Chris! Would it be possible to do it without any new traits?  I am trying to modernize Brotli crate, and it has a lot of auto-generated code, so slowly fixing it -- https://github.com/dropbox/rust-brotli/blob/6c4cd186f258685d38622fa422ebd2bb0090001b/src/enc/interface.rs#L547
